# Implementation MVC action OnAuthorization attr, which skip OnAuthorization attr in controller

Tags: c#, .net, security, model-view-controller, attributes

I have auth attribiute to controll access to controller

```
public class UserLevelAccessibilityAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{ 
       var baseController = filterContext.Controller as Controllers.BaseController;

        var userContext = baseController.UserContext;
        if (false == userContext.HasUserLevels(_levels))
        {
            var postData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            postData.Add("requiredLevels", string.Join(",", _levels));

            filterContext.Result = 
                new RedirectAndPostActionResult("/Error/Unauthorized", postData);
       }
}
```

In code it looks like

```
[UserLevelAccessibilityAttribute(EPermissionLevel.Pricing)]
public MyContr : Controller
{
    [SkipAuthorizationFromController]
    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
    }
 }
```

My question is how to implement **SkipAuthorizationFromController** attribute to skip controller's authorization? Or should I change UserLevelAccessibilityAttribute implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your custom attribute check if there is any SkipAuthorizationFromController attribute present on the action.

you can use below to do that

```
     actionContext
       .ActionDescriptor
       .GetCustomAttributes<SkipAuthorizationFromController>()
       .Any()
```